# Перемещение по экрану кастомного интерфейса без стандартной панели Windows PyQt6

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pyqt, pyqt6

Мне очень понравился интерфейс, [GitHub](https://github.com/Wanderson-Magalhaes/Python_PySide2_Custom_Title_Bar) где автор реализует перемещение интерфейса через виджет `QFrame` под названием `title_bar`. 
Я решил попробовать сделать также, с поправками на **`PyQt6`**.

**Frame.py**:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
    self.mainLayout.setObjectName("mainLayout")
    self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
    self.frame.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 30))
    self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
    self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
    self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
    self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
    self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.frame, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
    self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.StyledPanel)
    self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
    self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
    self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ТАЩИ"))
```

**func.py**:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import Frame

class InputsWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(InputsWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.ui = Frame.Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowType.FramelessWindowHint)

    def moveWindow(event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            pos = self.pos()
            glpos = event.globalPosition()
            self.move(pos + glpos - self.dragPos)
            self.dragPos = event.globalPosition()
            event.accept()

    self.ui.frame.mouseMoveEvent = moveWindow

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    self.dragPos = event.globalPosition()


if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = Frame.QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
Form = InputsWindow()
Form.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Всё просто: окно не имеет стандартной рамки, а перетаскивание должно работать по красному прямоугольник с надписью "ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ТАЩИ".

Но вылетает ошибка:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QPoint' and 'QPointF'

Вопрос: на что нужно обратить внимание в этом скрипте, чтобы он заработал по вашему мнению?

Под этим вопросом уже есть ответ, но, к сожалению, он также не помог. Я полностью переделал вопрос, надеюсь так гораздо понятнее. Думаю многим такая фича будет полезна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не могу проверить, но предложу попробовать (добавьте перед `self.move(...)`) :

```
print(f'QPointF --> QPoint: {QPoint(event.globalPosition().x(), event.globalPosition().y())}')
```

или

```
print(f'QPointF --> QPoint: {QPoint(int(event.globalPosition().x()), int(event.globalPosition().y()))}')
```

С `self.dragPos`, если что, надо проделать тоже самое.

**P.S.** Также почитайте https://www.qt.io/blog/input-events-in-qt-6 может что-то интересное найдете.

Comment: @AddmiX получилось ?

Comment: спасибо! я вставляю вашу строчку перед `self.move()` и мне пишет, что `QpointF object is not callable` Но я ещё не читал статью что вы прислали, возможно там тоже есть ответ.

Comment: на месте где стоит `QPoint` если оставить как есть, то будет вполне понятная ошибка `QPoint is not defined`, а если поставить переменную `pos`, то тогда `QPoint is not callable`.

Comment: отмечу ваш, потому что он натолкнул на решение =)

Answer (score 1):

В общем, решение очень простое лично для себя я подобрал. Просто применив метод `toPoint()` алгоритм работает:

```
    def moveWindow(event):
        if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
            pos = self.pos()
            glpos = event.globalPosition().toPoint()
            self.move(pos + glpos - self.dragPos.toPoint())
            self.dragPos = event.globalPosition()
            event.accept()
```